# Measure Area and perimeter form a boolean operation interactive

Tags: modifiers

Is there a way to obtain an area an perimeter from a boolean intersection operation?
To be more especific I have a head an a plane and I made a boolean intersection operation, so i have a section of the head where the plane intersects it.
I can measure area and perimeter with measurelt, but in order to do this i have to apply the bolean modifiern and then measure. 
The problem is I need still moding the head, and measure in the process to get a desired perimeter, so is like I need and interactive measurement.
My thougt is if it can be displayed it can be measured.....but really i dont know how.

Thanks in advance.

[image: section of the head intersected by plane]